# Why different facebook plugins using the same div id name?

Tags: facebook, plugins, html

We want to integrate the facebook login button plugin, facebook like button, facebook comments   with in one page for different purpose.

But we found that they all using the same div id #fb-root. As we know, one div id should be used only time for one page...

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one fb-root. The like button, login, etc will generate where you put the "like", "login", etc tags.

```
<div class="fb-like" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="true"></div>
```

"Include the JavaScript SDK on your page once, ideally right after the opening  tag."
This contains fb-root

Then, Place the code for your plugin wherever you want the plugin to appear on your page.